# Is there a Python function that allows to resample an imbalanced multi-class dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, resampling

I want to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) on a multi-class dataset. There's a class imbalance, so I want to upsample the minority classes.

The dataset looks as follows:

```
[Text 1, ["obscene", "insult"]],
[Text 2, ["identity_attack", "insult"]]
```

I tried to use the resample function from `sklearn.utils`. The problem is that if I upsample the obscene class by creating a duplicate of Text 1, I automatically upsample the insult class too.

Is there a Python function that solves my problem?

Comment: you can use augmentation only to selected classes

Comment: I have a function that does it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66283787/7747918